# Rust winapi wrapper for GetTokenInformation

Tags: winapi, rust, ffi

I'm having a hard time trying to create a helper wrapper for winapi call to [GetTokenInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation).

I was thinking about something like this:

```rust
/// The wrapper over GetTokenInformation
pub fn get_token_information(
    token_handle: winapi::um::winnt::HANDLE,
    token_information_class: u32
) -> Result<Box<[u8]>, _> {
    let mut required_len = 0;
    unsafe {
        winapi::um::securitybaseapi::GetTokenInformation(
            token_handle,
            token_information_class,
            std::ptr::null_mut(),
            0,
            &mut required_len,
        )

        let mut mem = vec![0u8; required_len as usize].into_boxed_slice();
        winapi::um::securitybaseapi::GetTokenInformation(
            token_handle,
            token_information_class,
            mem.as_mut_ptr() as _,
            required_len,
            &mut required_len,
        );

        Ok(mem)
    }
}

/// Sample function using get_token_information wrapper.
fn get_user_sid() {
    ...  
    let token_user = get_token_information(process_token_handle.0, winapi::um::winnt::TokenUser)?;
    let sid = unsafe {
        let ptr = token_user.as_ptr() as *const TOKEN_USER;
        convert_sid_to_string_sid((*ptr).User.Sid)?
    };
}
```

However I'm not sure about the return type. I would appreciate some hints how to make it cleaner.

**Update**
According to @cafce25 & @IInspectable answers the above code is pretty much ok for internal use. I will leave this question for a bit, as maybe someone will have some other concerns.

Comment: This is ok, for a very low level abstraction, it really depends on what your design goal is. But API design is very much opinion based and as such off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: A few notes: `1` `get_token_information()` never returns the `Err` variant since it never checks whether the API calls failed. If you don't have a reason to use the `winapi` crate, choose the [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate instead. It does the `BOOL` -> `Result` transformation for you. `2` Passing around byte slices isn't inherently wrong. At a public interface, I would wrap that behind a custom type. An `enum` would seem reasonable, given that `GetTokenInformation()` returns one of several different types, depending on the specific request.

Comment: It's not OK, not even for internal use. Error handling is the bare minimum required. As implemented, `get_token_information()` *can* return an empty slice, a pointer to which is subsequently reinterpreted as a pointer to a `TOKEN_USER` structure and then dereferenced. It's the type of bug that has haunted C code for literally half a century now. There's also the memory leak, which is not technically a memory safety issue. I'll see if I can find a moment to submit a formal answer. Are you required to use the `winapi` crate, though? I'd rather use `windows`/`windows-sys` if that is an option.

Comment: Scrap the comment on the memory leak. There isn't one. I must have been thinking of a different API.